# Can't connect to AWS instance using RDP client

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created and AWS instance and I want to connect to it using RDP client option, but after I've downloaded the remote desktop file an error dialog appears which says:
[image]

These are security group's details:
[image]

How can I connect to the instance?

Comment: Can you post your security group?

Comment: I have post it, can you please have a look on it? @StefanN

Comment: Firstly, you should probably better sanitize your screenshot, as it contains a lot of private info. Can you check that your Windows EC2 instance has public IP and that your public IP falls in the specified source range?

Comment: 18.130.73.238 - this is the public IPV4 address for my instance, and I have edited the security group inbound rules as above but I get the same error..